# How to check string contain A-Z or a-z or 0-9 in a string?(php)

Tags: php

How to identify if a string contain a-z or A-Z?
or contain 0-9?
I need an function to judge a string belong to alphabet type or number type.
Many thanks!!

Comment: sorry for asking the stupid question.What I had thought is to create an alphabet and digit array to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`ctype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) functions on PHP

[`ctype_alpha`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) and [`ctype_digit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) is probably what you are looking for.

**Usage:**

```
//For alphabets
if(ctype_alpha('helloworld'))
{
echo "Yeah this is text";
}
//For digits...
if(ctype_digit('45'))
{
echo "Yeah this is a number";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for this:

```
$string = "abasdfBSDFSDFJKJH23409283049";
if (preg_match("^/[A-Za-z0-9]$/", $string)) 
{
    //it matches
}
```